# C++ job interview questions?

Tags: c++

I am expecting a job interview for a C++, what kind of questions should I expect?

I have been programming with C for 5 years. I know what OOP is and I have been reading about it for some time. But it is most likely I can miss important details because I do not do anything real on C++.

Best Regards,

Comment: Good question, but wrong forum.

Comment: See if you can explain how to implement virtual inheritance as a compiler.

Comment: Thanks, Kerrek. I am sorry that the Q is o longer available. Which forum should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read "Programming Interviews Exposed - Secrets to Landing Your Next Job", it's a very good book for programming interviews.